# What is the difference between scalar array and vector array?

Tags: verilog

**First question**

Whether we declare the array as scalar or vector, we can access each element bit by bit. For example, we can declare two arrays below.

```
reg scalar_array[0:9];
reg [0:9] vector_array;  

always @*
begin
  scalar_array[0] = 1'b1;
  vector_array[0] = 1'b1;
end
```

I would like to know if the difference exists between two declarations.

---

**Second question**

Also, when I declare the two-dimensional array like below, I could access the entire row using the indexing operator[] for the variable declared using a below syntax.

```
reg[X:X] var_name [Y:Y];
```

However, I couldn't access the entire row when I declare the array using the below syntax.

```
reg var_name [X:X][Y:Y];
```

I would like to know how this concept can be synthesized on the hardware, and if they are both synthesizable, what is the difference between them.

```
reg [0:9] vector_array_2d [0:15];
reg scalar_array_2d[0:9][0:15];
always @*
begin
  vector_array_2d[0] = 'd1;
  scalar_array_2d[0] = 'd1; //raise the error!! 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, search for the [difference between packed and unpacked arrays](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/ovm/difference-between-packed-and-unpacked-arrays).

Your second question is a Verilog limitation with unpacked arrays - it only allows access to one array element at a time. SystemVerilog does not have this restriction. You can access an unpacked array as a whole, or select an entire dimension.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. However, it seems that Verilog doesn't support multiple packed dimensions. Vivado raise the error when I tried to declare the packed array like reg[3:0][4:0] packed_array;

Comment: Make sure you have turned on SystemVerilog, use a *.sv file extension.

Comment: this answer is specific to SystemVerilog, not Verilog

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344363/2658159

Comment: @AaronThomas SystemVerilog introduced the terminology "packed"and "unpacked", the functionality was the same as in Verilog. Although Verilog only allows a single packed dimension.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. would it be correct to say that for Verilog, a vector is a one-dimensional packed array? or is vector a different concept altogether?

Comment: In the Verilog, a vector is a one-dimensional packed array. In SystemVerilog, a vector is any packed array or packed struct. Integral/vector/packed are different words for the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the difference lies in how the register is to be treated - as either a bus (a single value, wider than one bit) or an array (multiple values, stored under one name). It seems a little bit philosophic, but [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/222192/255371) provides more detail.

For the second question, it may rely on the manufacturer or provider. For example, Xilinx Vivado will synthesize multi-dimensional arrays of up to two dimensions only (ref [UG901](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2020_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf)).